# Prevent dialog from closing on external intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-dialogfragment

I have some legacy code that has a small data entry form within a dialog (AlertDialog.Builder, DialogFragment). I need to add a help button, to explain a complex part of the form, that calls Intent.ACTION_VIEW to open up a help page in the browser (easy).

However, when the help button is clicked the dialog closes, and any data entered lost. Is there any way to keep this dialog open to preserve any data the user may have entered? So that when the user presses back after reading help in browser, they are in same state as they were previously?

Alternative option will be to store any data entered in memory and reopen dialog with data when app has focus, but seems excessive work if there is a simple flag or method that can be set.

App is developed for min SDK_10, compiled for SDK_23, build tools 23.0.3.

Comment: Thanks. My help button is an ImageView and not dialog default BUTTON_POSITIVE or _NEGATIVE (which are used in dialog), so I'm not sure I can use your solution (or at least it's not clear to me how to implement).